# Openhab2 openhabmin installation

Tags: openhab

I'm new at openhab2.

Within my installation / website I cannot find the menu point

Extensions/User Interfaces

to install e.g. openhabmin

How can I activate the menu point or what do I have to install?

System: RPi 3, Weezy
Path: /usr/share/openhab2

thank you very much in advance and best regards

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a running openHAB environment, the easiest way is to install additional UIs through the PaperUI.

- Visit `http://<openhabIP>:<port>` which will bring you to the dashboard.

  - Default Port is `8080` and the IP depends on the way you installed openHAB
- You can then navigate to `PaperUI` which is the default configuration UI.
- In `PaperUi` navigate to `Add-ons`and then chose the `USER INTERFACES` category
- There you can find all available UIs and install the UI of your choice
- After succesful installation you can access the newly installed ui trough the dashboard

There are other options for the installation of add-ons like uis.
You can find an article about this in the docs.
https://www.openhab.org/docs/configuration/addons.html